# Compiling Handlebars templates to html files

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm working on a scaffolding project for simple, no cms, html sites. Basically, the site runs off a simple node server, running express & handlebars, with handlebars `.hbs` template files and a `main.hbs` as the main layout. This is all for development purposes. When the site is ready to be pushed up somewhere, I want a build task that will render it into a completely static html site.

**My Problem**: I can't figure out how to get the html of a fully rendered page, from my handlebars templates, loaded into a node module I can then create HTML files from using the module like a build task eg. `node Build.js`. Here is some code to show you, basically, the main layout and home layout need to be compiled then given to me as a js string.

PS. I have the regular `handlebars` package aswell, I'm just using `express-handlebars` for the server part.

**server.js (irrelevant parts taken out)**

```
// -----------------------------
// Dependancies
// -----------------------------

// https://www.npmjs.com/package/express
var express = require('express');

// https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars
var exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');


// -----------------------------
// Template Engine
// -----------------------------

// Specify template engine & it's config
app.exp.engine('.hbs', exphbs({ extname: '.hbs', defaultLayout: 'main' }));

// Set the engine defined above
app.exp.set('view engine', '.hbs');


// -----------------------------
// Apply the routes to our application
// -----------------------------
app.exp.use(express.static(__dirname), app.router);


// -----------------------------
// Routes
// -----------------------------

// Home Route
app.router.get('/', getRoute);

// Route Controller
app.router.get('/:page', getRoute);

// Formats page data and renders the template
function getRoute(req, res) {

  // If homepage, set some data
  if(req.url === '/') req.params.page = 'home';

  // Capitalize the route param for the page title
  var title = req.params.page.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + req.params.page.substr(1);

  // Render the view
  res.render(req.params.page, {
    name: app.name,
    title: title,
    class: req.params.page
  });

}

app.exp.listen(app.port);
```

**Main layout (the standard html guts, the {{body}} data is where the template files are loaded into)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title>{{title}} - {{name}}</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body class="page-{{class}}">

  <!-- Navigation -->
  {{> nav}}

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <main>
    {{{body}}}
  </main>

</body>
</html>
```

**And just for example, the home template**

```
<div>
  <p>
    This is the homepage.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to do the same thing, hope we get some answers!

Comment: I want to do EXACTLY this but cannot if I am using routing in my application. Gulp-Compile-Handlebars works if you don't use routes, but I want to use routes for development and ship the static files.